# Is there a stackoverflow question answer framework available?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack Overflow Clones?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones)

I was rececntly browsing the web in search for a Dynamic DNS solution and stumble upon this [website](http://www.dyndnscommunity.com/) . As you can see their site's question and answer is identical to stackoverflow so i was wondering if there was a framework that they are using in order to achieve that...
I apologize in advance if my question should't be asked here but i didn't know where else to post it whithout making people angry.

Comment: see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones

Comment: Although the site you refer to in particular uses Stack Exchange, the hosted version of the Stack Overflow engine. http://stackexchange.com

Comment: No worries, this is the right place to ask, it's just a common question =)